# How to get the css file path in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.4

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="magento/skin/frontend/default/default/css/styles.css" media="all" />
```

how can i get this path in magento ?

i have tried this code but it didn't work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('css/styles.css');?>">
```

Comment: where are you trying to get this in phtml file? and make sure your current theme is default

Comment: i have been trying to get this file here app/design/frontend/base/defaulttemplate/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml

Comment: what is output of this code because i can't find any problem in code.

Comment: it isn't working

Comment: can you share the output of this code and make sure you editing the correct file

Comment: i just want to add css file in my file there is nothing for output

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('css/styles.css');?>">` you are using this code and it not working for you that is your problem?

Comment: yes this is my prob

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51230/discussion-between-qaisar-satti-and-afzal-khan).

Answer (score 2):

Replace Code With:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl(); ?>css/yourCssfile.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: not working....

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('custom.css') ?>" />
```

Comment: not working for me (Magento 1.9.2.2). @h-parekh working for me